# Caesar Cipher: How to print from dictionary *all* letters from input?

Tags: python

When I run this with the input "abc", it prints only "f", instead of "def" and I can't figure out why... help

```
code = raw_input("Enter your code: ")

translation = {"a": "d", "b": "e", "c": "f", "d": "g", "e": "h", "f": "i", "g": "j", "h": "k", "i": "l", "j": "m", "k": "n", "l": "o", "m": "p", "n": "q", "o": "r", "p": "s", "q": "t", "r": "u", "s": "v", "t": "w", "u": "x", "v": "y", "w": "z", "x": "a", "y": "b", "z": "c"}

lettered_code = list(code)

def translate(lettered_code):
    for letters in lettered_code:
        newanswer = translation[letters]
    return newanswer

print translate(lettered_code)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only return the last translation, you are setiing `newanswer = translation[letters]` each iteration so you only see the last.

Add each new char to a string:

```
def translate(lettered_code):
    new_answer = "" # set variable outside the for loop to an empty string
    for letters in lettered_code:
        new_answer += translation[letters] # add each translated letter to new_answer
    return new_answer # return all joined letters
```

You don't need `lettered_code = list(code)`, you can iterate over a string directly so just pass `code` into your function.

You can also use [join](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) and a [list comprehension](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/lists/list-comprehensions-in-python/) which creates a list of the translated chars and joins them into a single string:

```
def translate(lettered_code):
    "".join([translation[letters] for letters in lettered_code ])
```

Comment: Why do you just put two quotation marks as being equal to newanswer?

Comment: that is an empty string, you are adding to that empty string each time through your loop

Answer (score -1):

You are returning early, you want

```
def translate(lettered_code):
    return [translation[letter] for letter in lettered_code]
```

Comment: This returns a list, not a string. If you want to use comprehensions, you could do `''.join(translation[letter] for letter in lettered_code)` that returns a string and avoids creating extra lists.